# How do I apply the same function to each value in an array of dicts?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have an array of dicts, each array having the same keys.  For example

```
arr_of_dicts = ({"st" : "il"}, {"st" : "IL"}, {"st" : "Il"})
```

How do I apply the same function to a certain key's value in each dict?  For example, I would like to apply the uppercase function to the value making the above

```
arr_of_dicts = ({"st" : "IL"}, {"st" : "IL"}, {"st" : "IL"})
```

?

Comment: Use a `for` loop and `d['st'] = d['st'].upper()` ?

Comment: Is something that can be done in one line?  When I tried this in the Python console, "for d in arr_of_dicts: d['st'] = d['st'].upper()" nothing came back, just "..."

Comment: You should do it in two lines. Nothing will comeback — that will alter the original dict. If you print the dict after that you should see the updated dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), you can make your transformation function accept a key to transform and return a lambda, which acts as the mapping method. By using the previously passed key (`k`) and the passed in dictionary (`d`), you can return a new dictionary with the dictionary's value converted to uppercase:

```
arr_of_dicts = ({"st" : "il"}, {"st" : "IL"}, {"st" : "Il"})

upper = lambda k: lambda d: {k: d[k].upper()} # your func
res = map(upper('st'), arr_of_dicts) # mapping method

print(list(res))
```

**Result:**

```
[{'st': 'IL'}, {'st': 'IL'}, {'st': 'IL'}]
```

---

If your dictionaries have additional keys, then you can first spread the original dictionary into your new dictionary, and then overwrite the key propery you want to transform with the uppercase version like so:

```
arr_of_dicts = [{"a": 5, "st" : "il"}, {"a": 7, "st" : "IL"}, {"a": 8, "st" : "Il"}]

upper = lambda k: lambda d: {**d, k: d[k].upper()}
res = map(upper('st'), arr_of_dicts) # mapping method

print(list(res))
```

**Result:**

```
[{'a': 5, 'st': 'IL'}, {'a': 7, 'st': 'IL'}, {'a': 8, 'st': 'IL'}]
```

Comment: I was hoping to get back an array of dicts, like the input.  Does "tuple(res)" have the same array of dicts type?

Comment: by array do you mean list? You can use `list(res)` for a list (does that give you the result you're after?)

Comment: Yes good call, I meant "list" (kind of new to Python).  Here's the issue.  If the "arr_of_dicts" var contains 'arr_of_dicts = ({"a": 5, "st" : "il"}, {"a": 7, "st" : "IL"}, {"a": 8, "st" : "Il"})', running the above removes all the key-value pairs in which the key isn't "st".  Is there a way to preserve the structure all dicts and only upper case the value tied to the "st" key?

Answer (score 0):

**You might also like pandas.**

If you do a lot of stuff like this, you should check into [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) and its [apply functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). It can make these sorts of things as quick as:

```py
df = df.apply(your_func)
```

It's a really powerful tool and you can sometimes make some slick and handy one-liners if that's your kind of thing.